# How to take screenshots of a Flex Spark VideoDisplay?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, adobe, screenshot, videodisplay

I want to build a component, where the user can play a video in a Flex Spark VideoDisplay. There will be a button and whenever the button is pressed, I want to save the current time of the VideoDisplay plus a screenshot. The screenshot needs to be someway saved, because I want to display all times and screenshots in a DataGrid (screenshots should appear when the user hovers a time in the DataGrid).

So, how can I take screenshots of the Spark VideoDisplay and save/display them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take snapshots a few ways, this way just uses the ImageSnapshot class, but you could do it by manually drawing the bitmap of the video display if you'd like.  Here's a sample:

**Renderer**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="100" height="100" creationComplete="trace(data)">

    <mx:Image source="{this.data}" width="100%" height="100%"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**Sample App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;

            public function takeSnapshot():void
            {
                var snapshot:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(videoDisplay);
                var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(snapshot);
                list.dataProvider.addItem(bitmap);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay"
        source="video.mov"
        width="400" height="300"/>

    <s:Button id="button" click="takeSnapshot()"/>

    <s:List id="list" horizontalCenter="0" width="100%" itemRenderer="SnapshotRenderer">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayList/>
        </s:dataProvider>
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout/>
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>
</s:Application>
```

To accomplish exactly what you were describing (take snapshot and save snapshot), you could store those in an array in that `takeSnapshot` method, or you could loop through the `list.dataProvider` do get the bitmaps.  Then you'd just need to pass them to a backend language (ruby, python, php...) to save.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: Thanks! I don't actually want to save them. They should just be available to the user while he is playing the video.

Answer (score 1):

use the JPEGEncoder in flex to convert it to bytearray, and then encode the byte array using the b64encoder as follow:

```
var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);        

var b64encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
b64encoder.encodeBytes(ba);
var b64String:String = b64encoder.flush();
```

Now you can pass your b64String to your server via HTTP post method :)